# AMD module requires result of AJAX call

Tags: ajax, module, requirejs, amd

Can I define an AMD module whose dependency is the result of a dynamic AJAX call?

For example:

```
define([ 'jquery', 'config' ], function ($, config) {
    $.get(config.API + 'getSomething', { key: config.KEY }).done(function (res) {
        // I want res to be what this module returns
    });
});
```

I can do this:

```
define([ 'jquery', 'config' ], function ($, config) {
    return $.get(config.API + 'getSomething', { key: config.KEY });
});
```

But then whenever I require this module, I have to attach a `done`, which I'd rather not do:

```
define([ 'something-module' ], function (something) {
    something.done(function (res) {
        // All my codes here
    });
});
```

It'd be cleaner if I could wait for the result of the API call before considering the module to be loaded and then return the result of that call, but I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

The result of AMD module can be any type of object

Based on [Jquery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you can set async paramter to false and block process to complete the request

> Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active

I recommend you to return Promises as a result of module which can fulfill or reject in future and avoid blocking browser.